# Проблема с ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Tags: ubuntu

Не устанавливается ни одно приложение и не обновляется даже.. ubuntu 11.04 когда пишу `sudo apt-get update`мне пишет

```
Чтение пакетов... Ошибка! E: Malformed 1st word in the Status lineE: Произошла ошибка во время обработки ttf-mscorefonts-installer (UsePackage3)E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/statusE: Списки пакетов или status-файл не могут быть открыты или прочитаны.
```

Пробовал удалить установить `mscorefonts`, не получается... пишет ошибку

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer && sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installerЧтение списков пакетов... Ошибка!E: Malformed 1st word in the Status lineE: Произошла ошибка во время обработки ttf-mscorefonts-installer (UsePackage3)E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/dpkg/statusE: Списки пакетов или status-файл не могут быть открыты или прочитаны.
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить все в директории `lists` примерно так:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

а потом , как обычно:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Пишет W: Ошибка GPG: http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release: Следующие подписи не могут быть проверены, так как недоступен открытый ключ: NO_PUBKEY 9BDB3D89CE49EC21 после update

Comment: С ключом я разобрался, только когда устанавливаю deb пакеты пишетПроизошла непреодолимая ошибкаСудя по всему, в aptdaemon, программном обеспечении, позволяющем вам устанавливать/удалять программы и выполнять связанные с пакетами задачи, присутствует программная ошибка.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 965, in simulatetrans.unauthenticated = self._simulate_helper(trans)File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/worker.py", line 1089, in _simulate_helper    return depends, self._cache.required_download, \  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 226, in required_download    pm.get_archives(fetcher, self._list, self._records)SystemError: E:I wasn't able to locate file for the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package. This might mean you need to manually fix this package.

Comment: Все сам разобрался, обновил ключи и переустановил mscorefonts

Comment: @alexanderbarakin вы передумали насчет вредительского?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да. мне спросонок показалось, что предлагается удалить что-то из `/var/lib/dpkg/`, ведь именно с содержимым файла `status` проблемы у задавшего вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin с утра сразу за SO? :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, скорее — сразу за компьютер. а там s.o. открыт на одной из вкладок.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, кстати моя (иногда) довольно быстрая реакция на сообщения объясняется не тем, что я в это время рассматриваю какую-нибудь из страниц s.o., а тем, что я обратил внимание на «всписк» мобильного клиента s.o. (он только ради этих «всписов» и стоит на смартфоне — в остальном он (для меня) абсолютно «неюзабелен»).

Comment: Ага, точно с той же целью его использую.